BigQuery converts array<some-type> to a plain <some-type> field when loading a Firestore Export if the array is empty?
recently I've been working with Firestore Exports and loading them to tables in BigQuery to finally run some processing, and I've faced a weird situation. First here's some context:
Process:

The source data is stored in Firestore
I trigger the generation of a Firestore export based on an event in the system and store it in GCS
I load the export from GCS to BigQuery
I run a transformation query over the table

Data models considerations:

Now, in my data structure in Firestore, I have a field which is defined as an array<string>, which can or cannot contain elements for each document.
The transformation query that I'm running does an UNNEST operation over that array.

The problem:
According to the Google documentation, arrays in Firestore should be converted to an array in BigQuery (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#data_type_conversion).
However, when it happens the specific scenario that none of the documents in Firestore have any values in the array (i.e. the arrays are empty), in the loaded BigQuery table that field turned out as a plain string with NULLABLE mode instead of REPEATED. Because of this, the query is failing to unnest that specific field.
According to the GCP documentation, an ARRAY is an ordered list of zero or more elements of any non-array type (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_type), so I was expecting that empty arrays in Firestore would turn out to be empty arrays in BigQuery, unless I'm missing something else.
I couldn't do much given that you're not allowed to specify a schema at loading time, as it is derived from the same Firestore export file directly. The only thing I tried is that as long as there's at least one element in the array of at least one document in Firestore, then the type is converted correctly to an array in BigQuery. But I have no control over the data generated in the system and it is a bit hacky to just add e.g. a single empty string by default to arrays that are empty so that BigQuery would do the type conversion properly. Another option is to preprocess that table and convert the field to an empty array if it is null. In any case, I can try to solve it before processing the table, but I was wondering if there's any other thing I could do to sort this out?
